# Using android platform with java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, platform

I made a game using eclipse(java), do i have to only download android platform to make it an app, or i have to download java as will, (i have eclipse on my computer already)?

Comment: Eclipse has not been supported for Android development for a long time now, [tag:android-studio] is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No dont have to install android platform, you can install the android software development kit and add ADT Plugin